# how to padd output of the SET /P?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I am using this simple menu in cmd where I padded my ECHOs with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key:

```
:MENU

ECHO    select this by pressing 0
ECHO(
ECHO    select this by pressing 1
ECHO(
SET /P ANSWER="press something:"
```

is there a way how to padd the output of `SET /P ANSWER=` ??

I tried with <kbd>TAB</kbd> it and/or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> it, but non works. it looks like this:

```
     select this by pressing 0

     select this by pressing 1

press something:_
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
     select this by pressing 0

     select this by pressing 1

     press something:_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some control character e.g. backspace (`U+0008`) as in the following code snippet; a hint: single key-presses can be captured from the keyboard using [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) (see the script)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

     rem get backspace character to BS variable
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set BS=%%a

:MENU
ECHO(
ECHO    select this by pressing 0
ECHO(
ECHO    select that by pressing 1
ECHO(
     rem       ↓ this character is deleted in output by backspace
SET /P "ANSWER=X%BS%   press something: "
ECHO(
echo    "%ANSWER%" entered; another approach using CHOICE command:
ECHO(
CHOICE /C 01 /N /M "X%BS%   Select [0] this or [1] that: "
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1324661.bat

   select this by pressing 0

   select that by pressing 1

   press something: s

   "s" entered; another approach using CHOICE command:

   Select [0] this or [1] that: 1

==>
```